# Get URL hash value from the server in asp.net mvc using URL.Referrer

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, url, hash

Is there any way to retain or pass the hash value of a url to the server using Url.Referrer

For example,
I have a view with 3 bootstrap tabs (tab1, tab2 and tab3), when a user clicks on a tab, it hashes the URL, thus if someone types the url directly we set the correct tab.

This is how a url looks like

```
https://localhost:8080/myitems#tab2
```

This is the jquery code to hash and scroll to the tab

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
hash && $('ul.nav a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');

$('.nav-tabs a').click(function(e) {
    $(this).tab('show');
    var scrollmem = $('body').scrollTop();
    window.location.hash = this.hash;
    $('html, body').scrollTop(scrollmem);
});
```

The problem is, in one of the tab, it has an edit link that opens a new page, in the new page it has a go back button using URL.Referrer. If I mouse over on the link, I doesn't show the hash part of the URL.

So, my question is, is there any way it can send or retain the hash value to the server?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

No... hash is not sent so server and is only used by the browser.

There is no way to intercept that.

I don't quite understand your tab link logic and suspect you will need to change the way you manage that link.

Perhaps you could use a cookie or localStorage and javascript to manage it